# Highlight the text before a Wikipedia template

Tags: mediawiki

Wikipedia has some templates that can be used to highlight the text that precedes a template (for example, `{{clarify span|text to clarify}}` and `{{citation needed span|text to cite}}`).  Would it be possible to create a MediaWiki template to highlight text next to any template (in this case, using `{{further explanation needed}}` as the template)?

`{{clarifyUsingTemplate|{{further explanation needed}}|This is the text to clarify}}`.

Comment: I'm basically trying to create a template that would allow any template to be used with highlighted text, like the `{{clarify span|text to clarify}}` or `{{citation needed span|text with citation needed}}`, except with the spanning template as the second parameter.

Comment: Here's the source code of the `{{citation needed span}}` template - perhaps it could be modified in order to create a template like the one that I'm describing here. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Citation_needed_span&action=edit

Comment: @svick I haven't created any new templates yet, since I don't want my edits to be reverted. Is there any kind of "template sandbox" on Wikipedia where editors can test template syntax?

Comment: There is [Template sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Template_sandbox) and you can also create a sandbox in [your user space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:User_pages), which can then be transcluded to other testing pages.

Comment: @svick I'm still trying to figure out how to include strings with equals signs (and other special characters) as parameters. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40016/equals-signs-in-wikipedia-template-parameters-wont-display-properly